# Can I connect computers between two routers?

Tags: windows, networking, router, wifi, file-sharing

Sorry in advance, I'm not a big networking guy. The best way to illustrate what I'm asking is to show it in this diagram:

[image]

I need to be able to establish file sharing on Windows from "Laptop" to "PC-1" and "PC-2". Laptop is running Windows 10 Pro, and both PCs have Windows 7 Pro.

Things I **cannot do**:

- Rewire this setup.

Things I can do:

- Change admin configuration on any router.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: What router is it? Some have a setting that allows for the wireless network to be bridged to the LAN. Can you ping PC-1/PC-2 from the Laptop?

Comment: @YevhenStasiv: No, the ping doesn't go through. And the Wi-Fi router is Netgear XR500 with Duma OS.

Comment: The ports marked `LAN` on the Wi-Fi router are usually bridged with the wireless network. All you'll have to do to have a single broadcast domain will be deactivating `DHCP` on the Wi-Fi router (write down its address just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Can you create static routes on both devices? If so, create a static route telling each router to get to the other's network, pass through the connected interface